# Cardinality of a set of permutations of integers mod $p$.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $p$ be a prime number. I wonder if there is a closed formula for the number of permutations $\sigma$ of $ \{0,1,\ldots ,p-1\}$ such that 
$$\sum_x x \cdot \sigma(x) \equiv 0 \mod p$$

Obs: The hypothesis $p$ prime may not be required, but I am mostly interested in this case.

As an example, the identity permutation $\sigma(x) \equiv x$ is such, if $p > 3$.

What I did so far. Let's denote by $S(\sigma)$ the sum $\sum x \sigma(x)$.

-- $S(a \sigma + b) = S(\sigma)$ if $a$ is non null mod $p$

--The non-zero fibers of the map $S\colon Sym(p) \to \mathbb{Z}/p$ have the same cardinality  multiple of $p$ and the zero fibre has cardinality multiple of $p(p-1)$.

Comment: Something to try: Calculate the number for the first few primes, and plug the results into the OEIS, here: https://oeis.org/
It may not give you precisely the answer you want, but it could be a helpful start at what the closed form might be.

Comment: Good advice, @bburGsamohT .  It leads to < https://oeis.org/A004204 >, and I suspect the Graham and Lehmer reference there may be useful.

Comment: Thank you all!   @Robert Israel:  Great link + reference